# How to check that 'undefined' is there inside an array with indexOf method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

if i have my array like this

```
 A = ["1111", "22", "33", undefined, "55", undefined] ;
```

i got this array by delete some elements

I need to find the if there is an undefined inside an array without looping

```
A.indexOf('undefined') or A.indexOf(undefined)  .. wont work
```

so how can i check that undefined is there inside this array with indexOf method ?

Comment: `A.indexOf(undefined)` should work fine.

Comment: `> ["1111", "22", "33", undefined, "55", undefined].indexOf(undefined);` outputs 3 (as expected) when I try it.

Comment: If you are expecting the answer to be two, then to me that implies you want to know how many undefined elements exist in your array.

Comment: @SarathSaleem: *"is it 3 ..??? i want 2 :P"* `indexOf` returns the **index** of the **first** matching element, not a count of matching elements.

Answer (score 4):

Re your comment below:

> What i need is var A = ["1111", "22", "33", undefined, "55", undefined] ; in A i need to remove all undefined by splice methd a nd get the array like A = ["1111", "22", "33","55"]

That's a ***completely*** different question from your original. You can do that with the new ES5 [`Array#filter`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) function, which is shimmable (search for "ES5 shim") on pre-ES5 systems, like this:

```
A = A.filter(function(val) {
    return val !== undefined;
});
```

Or with a `for` loop and [`Array#splice`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)):

```
var index;
for (index = A.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
    if (A[index] === undefined) {
        A.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

---

Original answer to the `indexOf` question:

You've said that `A.indexOf(undefined)` isn't working for you. It should, provided that the `undefined` in `A` really is the `undefined` you're testing against. (Whereas `A.indexOf('undefined')` is, of course, not going to work unless you have the string `"undefined"` in your array.)

In the normal course of things, this will output `3`:

```
var A = ["1111", "22", "33", undefined, "55", undefined] ;
console.log(A.indexOf(undefined));
```

You've said it doesn't, though, so here are some reasons it might not and what to do about them:

1. You're expecting `indexOf` to find an `undefined` value for an array element that doesn't exist. E.g., **not**

   ```
   var A = ["1111", "22", "33", undefined, "55", undefined] ;
   console.log(A.indexOf(undefined)); // 3
   ```

   ...but instead:

   ```
   var A = [];
   A.length = 6;
   A[0] = "1111";
   A[1] = "22";
   A[2] = "33";
   A[4] = "55";
   console.log(A.indexOf(undefined)); // -1
   ```

   The reason is that there's a difference between an array that actually has an element with the value `undefined`, and an array that doesn't have that element **at all**. JavaScript arrays can be sparse, meaning they have gaps in them. (In fact, JavaScript arrays aren't really arrays at all.) Those gaps are skipped by `indexOf`.

   If you want to find `undefined` values *or* a gap, you can use a for loop:

   ```
   var i, index = -1;
   for (i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
       if (A[i] === undefined) {
           index = i;
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

   That works because `A[i]` will evaluate to `undefined` for either of two reasons: A) The element exists and it has the value `undefined`, or B) The element doesn't exist at all.
2. You've gotten `A` from another window. Sadly, the `undefined` in one `window` is not `===` the `undefined` in another window, and `indexOf` uses `===`. In that case, you can use [`some`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.17) instead (on modern browsers that have ES5, or using an ES5 shim):

   ```
   var A = /* ...get A from another window... */;
   var index = -1;
   A.some(function(val, i) {
       if (typeof val === "undefined") {
           index = i;
           return true;
       }
   });
   console.log(index); // 3
   ```

   Or just a `for` loop:

   ```
   var i, index = -1;
   for (i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
       if (typeof A[i] === "undefined") {
           index = i;
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

   Although `undefined` in one window doesn't `===` `undefined` in another window, they both have `typeof "undefined"`, so the above works around that problem.
3. You're including a library that mindlessly replaces `Array#indexOf` with its own, broken version of it. You can find out whether that's the case by doing this:

   ```
   console.log(A.indexOf);
   ```

   You should see something roughly like this:

   ```
   function indexOf() {
       [native code]
   }
   ```

   If you see real source code instead, someone's shimmed it (possibly even shimmed it without checking first if the browser already had it). If they have, and it's broken in this way, stop using that library. :-)
4. Some eejit has redefined `undefined` in one of the contexts, for instance like this:

   ```
   var A = ["1111", "22", "33", undefined, "55", undefined] ;
   (function(undefined) {
       console.log(A.indexOf(undefined)); // Outputs -1
   })("foo"));
   ```

   Or

   ```
   var A = (function(undefined) {
       return ["1111", "22", "33", undefined, "55", undefined] ;
   ])("foo");
   console.log(A.indexOf(undefined)); // Outputs -1
   ```

   If they've done that, track them down and flog them.

Comment: What i need is var A = ["1111", "22", "33", undefined, "55", undefined] ; in A i need to remove all undefined by splice methd a nd get the array like A = ["1111", "22", "33","55"]

Comment: @SarathSaleem: That's a ***completely*** different thing than `indexOf` not working. See above.

Comment: It might be worth adding that if the array was created with the constructor `new Array(5)` those empty slots will not match the `.indexOf(undefined)` check either.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove all the undefined items, I think you can do it pretty fast this way:

```
var A = ["1111", "22", "33", undefined, "55", undefined];

var item = undefined; // value of the item to remove, it can be anything actually

while (A.indexOf(item) > -1) {
 dataArr.splice(A.indexOf(item), 1);
}

console.log(A); // output
```